# How to utilize CSS only button markup?

Tags: html, css

For my curiosity, given a CSS-only button markup like this one: http://www.cssbutton.me/ryanjohnson_me/4fea99463f2df0f605000043, one can create a button *visually* using:

```
<div class="button">Click</div>
```

But how can we actually make it *functional*? For example, make it link to some other page, so when user clicks on it, she gets redirected.

I've tried wrapping a `<a href>` inside the `<div>`, but the button text shows up as a link, which is undesirable. I also tried the opposite - wrapping the `<div>` inside a `<a href>`, which seems to work but I was told this is not valid html code.

Any other suggestion?

P.S. The targeted browsers would be IE8+, chrome 14+, Firefox 11+, Safari 5+ and Opera 11+, if this makes any difference.

Comment: This would probably be hell on accessibility, screen-readers, and non-CSS users.

Comment: While  `<a><div /></a>` is technically not valid HTML, modern browsers should handle it fine.  See also: "semantic web" discussions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried changing the

`<div class="button">Click</div>`

into `<a class="button" href="#your_link">Click</a>`?

It should work as a normal link, and have the css buttons stylings and expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Use JavaScript to bind an action to the button.

```
function addEventHandler(elem,eventType,handler) {
     if (elem.addEventListener)
         elem.addEventListener (eventType,handler,false);
     else if (elem.attachEvent)
         elem.attachEvent ('on'+eventType,handler); 
}

addEventHandler(document.getElementById('yourButton'), 'click', function(e) {
    document.location.href = "newpage.html";
});
```

Comment: thanks for the js solution, but a simpler html tag solves it.

Comment: It works for this case, but you can use the JS approach if you want to do anything more complicated than a link to a bookmark or another page.

Comment: very true, will adopt the js approach for more complicated cases. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Add to the css:

```
a.button { text-decoration: none; }
```

To create button links:

```
<a class="button" href="/somewhere.html">Somewhere</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. I combined this with @VKen's answer above, and it gives the desired visual effect.

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript, specifically [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can do

```
  <div class="button" id="myButton">Click</div>


  $("#myButton").click(function()
  {
       location.href = "mypage.htm";
  });
```